# NServiceBus XML Serializer Error

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NSB 3.0.3. Here are my projects:

- Registrations.Messages (All events are command messages are here)
- Registrations.Domain
- Registrations.EventStorage
- Registrations.MessageHandlers
- Registrations.Server

Registrations.Server is using the NServiceBus.Host to host nsb. The endpoint config is here:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    #region Implementation of IWantCustomInitialization

    public void Init()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(new BackendModule());

        Configure.With()
            .NinjectBuilder(kernel);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The configuration of server is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig"
             type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig"
             type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
</configSections>

<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />

<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
        <add Messages="Registrations.Messages"
             Endpoint="Accounts.Server"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

I created a test console app to send a command from. Everything works until when NSB publishes a message. The exception is below:

I created my class to wrap the NSB:

```
public class NsbBus : IEventBus
{
    private readonly IBus m_nsb;

    public NsbBus(IBus nsb)
    {
        m_nsb = nsb;
    }

    #region Implementation of IEventBus

    public void Publish<T>(T @event) where T : class, IEvent<IIdentity>
    {
        m_nsb.Publish(@event);
    }

    public void PublishAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> events) where T : class, IEvent<IIdentity>
    {
        m_nsb.Publish(events);
    }

    #endregion
}

Type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Aec.Cqrs.IEvent`1[[Aec.Cqrs.IIdentity, Aec.Cqrs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Aec.Cqrs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] was not registered in the serializer. Check that it appears in the list of configured assemblies/types to scan.
```

That assembly Aec.Cqrs is referenced in the server project and deployed to the bin directory.

I looked at similar posts but they were about web projects. This is not a web project. Any ideas why the serialization error here?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why but this fixed the issue. Instead of passing the event collection to NSB's Publish method as collection, I called on Publish for each event.

        public void PublishAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> events) where T : class, IEvent<IIdentity>
        {
            foreach (var @event in events)
                m_nsb.Publish(@event);
        }

Comment: What was the exception you where getting? (not showing up in the Q)

Comment: Hi Andreas, the exception was part of last code region. Here it is again: Type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Aec.Cqrs.IEvent`1[[Aec.Cqrs.IIdentity, Aec.Cqrs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Aec.Cqrs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] was not registered in the serializer. Check that it appears in the list of configured assemblies/types to scan.

Comment: NSB thinks that you want to send the list as one message. Can you try to cast it to a IMessage[] and see if that helps?